# SQL Server query to know if an id in a column equals to other in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I’ve been hours trying to build this query and I need your help so I can make it. 
This is table `Students` (made out of inner joins):

```
SpecialtyChosenID  StudentID    Subject    SubjectSpecialtyID
5ABFB416-8137         15        Math          A1EBF3CB-E899
5ABFB416-8137         15        English       A1EBF3CB-E899
```

The info in it means that a student with id no. 15 has chosen an specialty with id `5ABFB416-8137`

The two subjects he has passed (Math and English) belong to a specialty with id `A1EBF3CB-E899`

What would be the query to know if the passed subjects belong to the specialty chosen by the student??

Counting the number of subjects with the same `SubjectSpecialtyID` as `SpecialtyChosenID` and vice versa could do.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This looks suspiciously like examples used to demonstrate 4NF/5NF database problems in CS courses.  If this is homework, please mark it as such.

Comment: No it is not homework, the students and subjects thing is an example I could have chosen cars or books. Plus no idea of what CS courses are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a self join. This finds the number of subjects taken by the student that match the student's chosen specialities.

```
SELECT l.SpecialtyChosenID, l.StudentID, Count(Distinct r.Subject) FROM Students l
LEFT JOIN Students r ON (l.StudentID=r.StudentID AND l.SpecialityChosenID=r.SubjectSpecialityID)
GROUP BY l.SpecialtyChosenID, l.StudentID
```

However, this is quite inefficient using the table structure given. If you have a table listing students with their specialities, and another with subjects and specialities, and a third relating students with subjects, it would be better to build this query from the base data, rather than from the derived data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE SpecialtyChosenID = SubjectSpecialtyID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the list of matching subjects and you have the SpecialtyChosenID you can do something like

```
SELECT * FROM Students
WHERE SubjectSpecialtyID = SpecialityChosenID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN SpecialtyChosenID = SubjectSpecialtyID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS specialty
```